# AutoComplete no Laravel

Tags: laravel

Eae galera td bem? então eu estou tentando desenvolver uma aplicação em Laravel e acontece que estou colocando um AutoComplete porém não esta rodando.
Por favor, me ajudem ai!

Este aqui é o ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#users').keyup(function () {
      var q=$(this).val();
      if(word.length>3) {

          $.ajax
          ({
              type: "GET",
              url: "/User/Dados",
              data: {q:q},
              contentType: "json",
              cache: false,
              success: function(data, status, xhr)
              {
                  $('#users').val(data[0].value);
              }
          });
      }
  });
```

Este aqui é o html

```
<i class="material-icons prefix">textsms</i>
      <input type="text" id="users" class="autocomplete">
      <label for="autocomplete-input">Pesquisar</label>
```

Este aqui é a Rota

```
Route::get('/User/Dados','User\UserController@buscar');
```

E finalizando este aqui é o Controller

```
public function buscar(Request $req){

  $user_date = $req->all();
  $users = User::all();
  $result = [];

  foreach ($users as $user) {
          $result[] = $user['name'];
  }
  return response()->json($result);}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigado Galera!

Comment: Nao seria `if(q.length > 3)` ao inves de `if(word.lenght > 3)` trocar o word pelo q no if?

Comment: cara, ainda n fez nada =(

Comment: Dê um `console.log( data )` para ver o que exibe

Comment: Troca também o keyup esse aqui `$('#users').on('keyup',function () `

Comment: sim, eu ja tinha trocado

Comment: vou ver o console

Comment: Pelo que vi, você quer consultar tudo o que tem na tabela User ao digitar, é isso mesmo?

Comment: sim, estou desejando fazer isto

Comment: Depois que você trocou o word pelo q você limpou o cache?

Comment: sim, limpei todo o cache e ainda ficou assim

Comment: vc testou? ou algo assim?